# Datepicker click event getdate

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, datepicker

I'm using [bootstrap datepicker](https://bootstrap-datepicker.readthedocs.org/en/latest/), and I want to triger click event to redirect to events page of the clicked date, I read the documentation of the datepicker for events, but there no click event, but it used `changeDate` and when I click on any date, I got that date and everything works fine, but when I click on any active date, I got random active date or repeat the last date.. how could I get clicked date even is that date is active ? [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fayekramzy/2L1ovhbm/)

Updated [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fayekramzy/2L1ovhbm/3/)

Comment: Its working fine http://jsfiddle.net/fayekramzy/2L1ovhbm/ cehck this fiddle.Its getting the selected date

Comment: try to click on more than one date to turn them active (blue), then click on them again .. you will see the problem @CodingCracker

Comment: you need to direct the page what u last clicked ?

Comment: exactly, its just one click, but I change the code just for testing, but on click event the page will redirect to events page with the clicked event. @CodingCracker

Comment: so u click the multiple dates? and u want to get last date what u clicked right ?

Comment: check my answer may be u need that

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Ok i tried many and many but no ideal solution, but i tried to add click trigger like this in [JSfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fayekramzy/2L1ovhbm/6/)

```
var months = ['January','February','March','April','May','June','July','August','September','October','November','December'];
$('.datepicker-days').on('click', 'td.day', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var dat = $(this).text();
    var monthyear = $(this).closest('table').find('.datepicker-switch').text().split(" ");
    var monthalpha = monthyear[0];
    var monthnum;
    console.log(months.indexOf(monthalpha));
    var year = monthyear[1];
    if($(this).hasClass('old')){
        monthnum = (months.indexOf(monthalpha));
    } else if($(this).hasClass('new')){
        monthnum = (months.indexOf(monthalpha)+2);
    } else {
        monthnum = (months.indexOf(monthalpha)+1);
    }
    if(monthnum > 12){
        monthnum = 1;
    } else if (monthnum < 1){
        monthnum = 12;
    }
    $('p').html(dat+"/"+monthnum+"/"+year);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this ,

```
$('div').datepicker({
    multidate: false,


});
```

Demo:http://jsfiddle.net/UI_Designer/2L1ovhbm/2/

Comment: after run the example, go to February for example and click on 5 , see what will happen !

Answer (score 0):

Just Use this may be You want this

```
$('div').on('changeDate', function(e){
  // extra 
  sdate = e.date.getDate() +'/'+ (e.date.getMonth()+1) + '/' + e.date.getFullYear();
  var getdate = $('p').html(sdate);  
  window.location.href = 'events.html?date='+getdate;
});
```

Comment: the problem not in the redirect, the problem is in the wrong date chosen, see the updated fiddle (http://jsfiddle.net/fayekramzy/2L1ovhbm/3/) after run click directly on 10 March , it will type 19 March !

Comment: I cant  get your problem

Comment: run the last fiddle and click on 10/3/2015 date and you will see the problem.

Comment: not yet, may be 'changeDate' event not the target function to get click event, it may triggered only for non-active dates.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('div').datepicker({
    multidate: false,
    todayHighlight: true,
    todayBtn: true
});
```

above code works fine.only selected date get printed.